# Why am i not getting the correct output?

Tags: c++, io

I'm new to C++ and having trouble with the io. The output is omitting the line Account Number: accountNumber and I have no idea why.

here is my display function.

```
void displayColumnTitle() 
{
  int accountNumber, balanceDue;
  string name;

  cout << "Enter Account Number(-1 to terminate the input):" << endl;
  cin >> accountNumber;
  cout << "Enter name: ";
  cin >> name;
  cout << "Enter balance due:" << endl;
  cin >> balanceDue;

  cout << "Account Number: " + accountNumber << endl
       << "Name: " + name << endl << "MONTH BALANCE DUE" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Use << not +. No concatenation.

Comment: `"Name: " + name` -> `"Name: " << name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Account Number: " + accountNumber
```

does not concatenate `accountNumber` to the string. Instead performs a pointer arithmetic operation. If `accountNumber` is `10`,

```
"Account Number: " + accountNumber
```

is equivalent to

```
"mber: "
```

I bet that's not what you expected.

Instead of

```
cout << "Account Number: " + accountNumber << endl
    << "Name: " + name << endl << "MONTH BALANCE DUE" << endl;
```

Use

```
//                         ||
//                         vv  Use << not +
cout << "Account Number: " << accountNumber << endl
    << "Name: " << name << endl << "MONTH BALANCE DUE" << endl;
//              ^^  Use << not +
//              ||
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is sure that **accountNumber** and **balanceDue** are of **integer** types.
So before you concatenate (using + operator between two strings) an integer with the string ,you need to convert integer to string,this can be done as ,

```
cout << "Account Number: " + std::to_string(accountNumber) << endl << 
"Name: " + name << endl << "MONTH BALANCE DUE" + std::to_string(balanceDue) << endl;
```

But we have other solution also as told by "R Sahu".